sequence of values in same column in r
I am trying to shuffle the values in the same column to have a different sequence in my output table
dat.stat.can.21$income.recode<-rep("40-99", length = dim(dat.stat.can.21)[1])
dat.stat.can.21$income.recode[dat.stat.can.21$HHInc<13]<-c("0-40")
dat.stat.can.21$income.recode[dat.stat.can.21$HHInc>24&dat.stat.can.21$HHInc<34]<-c("100+")
table(dat.stat.can.21$income.recode)

The table looks like this:
  0-40   100+  40-99 
 34670 200806 111532

I want to take 100+ in the 3rd column and bring the 40-99 in the second column. I tried by doing this:
dat.stat.can.21$income.recode<-rep("0-40", length = dim(dat.stat.can.21)[1])
dat.stat.can.21$income.recode[dat.stat.can.21$HHInc>12 & dat.stat.can.21$HHInc<25]<-c("40-99")
dat.stat.can.21$income.recode[dat.stat.can.21$HHInc>24&dat.stat.can.21$HHInc<34]<-c("100+")
table(dat.stat.can.21$income.recode)

But it is showing me same. Anybody has the idea what to do?

Welcome to Stackoverflow. You'll need to provide some data or this will be hopeless and this will likely be closed. You'll also want to 'show what you have', which may be merely the data, and 'what you want', in a trimmed down (reproducible) version. Typically, dput(head(dat.stat.can.21, n = some number of cases)), then you'd put my_data <- structure(...data..) above. To make code and data look like code and data, start such a block with three back tick and close it with three back ticks. Write your problem description above and below these blocks.

table(factor(dat.stat.can.21$income.recode, c('0-40', '40-99', '100+'))) should solve the problem

Using OrderMixed, since your table names are strings

order character strings containing
embedded numbers so that the numbers are numerically sorted rather
than sorted by character value

If this is your data
tab <- structure(c(`0-40` = 5L, `100+` = 3L, `40-99` = 2L), dim = 3L, 
dimnames = list(c("0-40", "100+", "40-99")), class = "table")

tab
 0-40  100+ 40-99 
    5     3     2

ordering the strings by numerical content gives
tab <- tab[DescTools::OrderMixed(names(tab))]

tab
 0-40 40-99  100+ 
    5     2     3


or tab[stringr::str_order(names(tab), numeric = TRUE)] but would still prefer the table(factor(dat.stat.can.21$income.recode, c('0-40', '40-99', '100+'))) as you define the order that you want

Do I need to use structure function while;e declaring the function?

Yeah, it is working. I have just applied:  table(factor(dat.stat.can.21$income.recode, c('0-40', '40-99', '100+'))). Thank you so much!

@Onyambu I interpreted the question to automatically order by numerical value, not arbitrarily impose an order. Both fine depending what you want.
